# Java 8 Base64 stream wrapper eats last two chars?

Tags: java, java-8, base64, kryo

I have the following code:

```
public static String encode(Object object)
{
    final String result;

    try (ByteArrayOutputStream bOut = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
         Output output = new Output(bOut))
    {
        KRYO.writeObject(output, object);
        output.flush();
        result = Base64.getUrlEncoder().encodeToString(bOut.toByteArray());
    } catch (IOException e)
    {
        // Do nothing, should never happen!
        throw new RuntimeException("MEGA FAIL");
    }

    return result;
}

public static String encodeTest(Object object)
{
    final String result;

    try (ByteArrayOutputStream bOut = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
         OutputStream base64Out = Base64.getUrlEncoder().wrap(bOut);
         Output output = new Output(base64Out))
    {
        KRYO.writeObject(output, object);
        output.flush();
        result = bOut.toString();
    } catch (IOException e)
    {
        // Do nothing, should never happen!
        throw new RuntimeException("MEGA FAIL");
    }

    return result;
}
```

Test:

```
String test = "asdf";
System.out.println(encode(test));
System.out.println(encodeTest(test));
```

gives the output (with kryo logger):

```
00:10 TRACE: [kryo] Write: asdf
00:10 TRACE: [kryo] Object graph complete.
YXNk5g==
00:10 TRACE: [kryo] Write: asdf
00:10 TRACE: [kryo] Object graph complete.
YXNk
```

So is there an error in my code?

Am I misusing the wrapper?

Is the error in kryo (tested with version 3.0.3 and 4.0.0)?

Comment: Do you have an input to reproduce the problem?

Comment: @shmosel updated the question. You can use any object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per the documentation for [`Base64.Encoder.wrap()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.Encoder.html#wrap-java.io.OutputStream-), you need to close the stream once you're done with it:

> It is recommended to promptly close the returned output stream after use, during which it will flush all possible leftover bytes to the underlying output stream.

Calling `bOut.toString()` after the encoder stream is closed will fix the problem:

```
public static String encodeTest(Object object)
{
    ByteArrayOutputStream bOut = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    try (OutputStream base64Out = Base64.getUrlEncoder().wrap(bOut);
         Output output = new Output(base64Out))
    {
        KRYO.writeObject(output, object);
    } catch (IOException e)
    {
        // Do nothing, should never happen!
        throw new RuntimeException("MEGA FAIL");
    }

    return bOut.toString();
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I thought flush would be enough,should read the docs more carefully.